# Faster code temperature sensors - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

Is there any way to optimize this process. Now it reads the textfiles sequentially but I want to do it parallel. Maybe by multiprocessing or threading?

```
# reading of temperature sensors
def findDS18B20raw1():
f1 = open(sensorfolder[0], 'r') # reading values from sensorfile
lines1 = f1.readlines()
f1.close()
return lines1[1]

def findDS18B20raw2():
f2 = open(sensorfolder[1], 'r')
lines2 = f2.readlines()
f2.close()
return lines2[1]

def findDS18B20raw3():
f3 = open(sensorfolder[2], 'r')
lines3 = f3.readlines()
f3.close()
return lines3[1]

def findDS18B20raw4():
f4 = open(sensorfolder[3], 'r')
lines4 = f4.readlines()
f4.close()
return lines4[1]

def findDS18B20raw5():
f5 = open(sensorfolder[4], 'r')
lines5 = f5.readlines()
f5.close()
return lines5[1]

def findDS18B20raw6():
f6 = open(sensorfolder[5], 'r')
lines6 = f6.readlines()
f6.close()
return lines6[1]
```

Pls help me

Comment: Threading will not make this faster. What is your issue? are the files huge?

Comment: The problem is that it is too slow. I want to read the text files and log the temeperature that are in the files. The files are only to lines.

My goal is to log every 2 seconds but the time to run the code is 5,4 seconds. Each "def finDS18B20raw" takes about 0,9 seconds.

Is there any other way to solve the problem? I tried Cython without improvement

Comment: Its seems slow, maybe due to the raspberry? I can test it on my raspberry when I have time. Do you use this for interface between two programs ? You could have all data in one file or try to avoid files at all, and keep it in memory ?

Comment: Yeah, probably is the Pi to slow. The DS18B20 temperature sensors saves the temperature on a text file. I would love to have all data and lines on one file. But don't know how to get that

Comment: Use python to read the temperature sensor... No need for files then. There is lots of examples out there. How are you reading it today ? What/who is writing those files ?